# Create-react-app don't run even just after create it

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

> *npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! github@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the github@0.1.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:*

or sometimes I am different kind of errors just after creating the app. which means no modifications to the default automatic generated project.

Answer (score 1):

and I managed to solved it.

the issue seems to be with my Yarn. incomplete uninstall or something like that. can't solve it by just reinstalling Yarn or uninstall it again. because of that, NPM create-react-app also create bugs, which IDK how.

but the solution is amazing, I just created the project in a different folder. trust me I'm not lying , different location do works in NPM. so I believe I need to format my computer to solve this 100%.

The cause maybe due to I have installed create-react-app via NPM globally and tries to install Yarn create-react-app. anyway, by using a different folder location, my issue was fixed completely.

Formatting the computer isn't a solution for this.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, but this problem sometimes also occurs when the permissions are not given on Windows. So the solution will be run CMD as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you probably have installed through `npm install -g create-react-app`
which is old version.

I think you need to uninstall and install again using `npx create-react-app`

**Steps**

1 - `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

or

```
yarn uninstall -g create-react-app
```

2 - `npx create-react-app my-app`

> npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm
>   versions.

check this [create-react-app latest one](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)